# Cloudera Command: hdfs dfs -put testfile.txt Failure

Tags: hadoop, terminal, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I use a MAC OS Yosemite with a cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0-virtualbox. I would like to put a "testfile.txt" in the HDFS. When I use the command "hdfs dfs -put testfile.txt" in the Terminal I have the Exception:

[image: Screenshot of the exception:]

what should I do?

Comment: In the "File Browser" TAB of the HUE I have the follow Error-Message: **Cannot access: /user/clouera. The HDFS REST service is not available. Note: You are a Hue admin but not a HDFS superuser (which is "hdfs").** ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the basic **`Hadoop`** services should be running when you start the **`Cloudera VM`**. Port **`8020`** is for the **`hadoop-hdfs-namenode`** service. These services must have failed and just needs to be restarted.

**To check the status of a service:**

```
service <service-name> status
```

**To restart a service:**

```
service <service-name> restart
```

To restart, **`hadoop-hdfs-namenode`** service

```
service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart
```

**if you get an Error -  "root user required",** **when restarting the service, run with sudo as shwon below:**

```
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart
```

if **`hadoop-hdfs-datanode`** service is also not running,

```
service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart
```

Alternatively, You can also start/stop/restart the service by login in to **`Cloudera Manager`** from Firefox in **`Cloudera VM`**.

Comment: Hi, @Vinkal, I have written in Terminal: **"service hadoop-hdfs-namenode status"** and the message was **"Hadoop namenode is dead and pid file exists [FAILED]"**. Then I tried **"service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart"** and I have got **Error: root user required**.

Comment: try with sudo: sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart

Comment: I tried and the message was: (1) **no namenode to stop** (2) **Stopped Hadoop namenode: [OK]** (3) **starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out** (4) **Failed to start Hadoop namenode. Return value: 1 [FAILED]**

Comment: Go through the log file. I guess, may be some permission issue.Check the permission for dfs.namenode.name.dir mentioned in hdfs-site.xml. Give the appropriate permission if that's the case.

Comment: Hi @Vinkal . I have found the "hdfs-site.xml" log file. By <value> from **dfs.namenode.name.dir** I have: "/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/name". What does that mean?In this case which permission must I give?

Comment: @JEFA - dump the content of log file. open the file - sudo gedit  /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-quickstart.cloudera.out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92635/discussion-between-vinkal-and-jefa).